# Запустил андроид приложение и кроме белого экрана в нем больше ничего нет

Tags: android, экран, app

Такое впервые. Подключил базу данных к проекту, начал запускать апп, после сборки проекта приложение запускается и появляется сплошной белый экран, никаких действий выполнить я не могу, в Android Monitor статус `No Debuggable processes,` то есть приложение по сути не загрузилось и не отвечает вообще.

Если откатиться на несколько коммитов назад где я еще не добавил сущности в бд, приложение запускается и работает ок. Понимаю что дело в моей базе данных, что гдето неправильно чтото сделал, но код показать здесь думаю плохая идея, ибо слишком много классов придется выкладывать здесь.

Пожалуйста подскажите, как выявить причину этого белого экрана? Как пофиксить этот белый экран смерти?

Comment: Без кода тяжело сказать что могло быть.  что за база данных? локальная или удаленная?Как вариант можно наставить кучу контрольных точек, и дебагере идти по ним и смотреть где виснет

Comment: @tosh17 Локальная бд, Greendao, попробую конечно так сделать, пока других вариантов не вижу...